# AWS Step Function Update Wait State

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

I have a Step Function in a CloudFormation Stack that has a wait state that waits anywhere from 1 day to two weeks. While the Step Function is waiting, I may choose to update the stack.  What happens to the wait state? Is it deleted and recreated? Does it wait until completion? Does CloudFormation throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you update.

Updating `DefinitionString` or `RoleArn` are [marked with "No interruption"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-stepfunctions-statemachine.html).

Generally, if you update a state machine,

> Running executions will continue to use the previous `definition` and `roleArn`.

([Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/stepfunctions/update-state-machine.html).)

Comment: Just to clarify, that is for running executions of the entire step function, and not just the individual state in the state machine, correct?

Comment: @PrestonM Correct.

Comment: is is possible to update the wait time of an individual state?